# A program that draws a spiral

Tags: python, beginner, fractals

To run this program the graphics.py module that is not in the standard library is needed and can be found here https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/

This amateur program is for the fun of graphics and programming in itself. Im thinking it would be a rewarding hobby for me to share and use each others shared code and therefore i would like to make it more programmer friendly.

Thinking out loud:

- The equations in this program are split into different lines for understandability.
- Is "understandability" a subcategory of readability?
- Or do they oppose and therefore should equations be shortened and the use of comments to clarify?
- Less rows but of intricate code or more rows of less intricate code?
- If its need for a programmer to reread compact intricate code comments or reread the other, is there a boundary between them other than semantics?
- Am I getting ahead of myself and it will be clearer down the road?

How can this program be made more programmer friendly?

```py
"""
Updated to be more programmer friendly

This is an implementation of John Zelles graphics.py module that is, as I understand it, a simple library of functions so that beginners can have some fun learning
graphics. The implementation paints smooth to scrambled spirals. Its free to use, edit etc.

In this code the "if command" buffers and flattens c.draw(win) while win is minimized and draws it flat when maximized

If enjoyable perhaps a filmscreen to capture as the computer paints? Or maybe a screensaver by just showing a number of brushstrokes at a time?

Thx to Reinderien comments and answer in Code Review Stack Exchange
"""

from math import *
from graphics import *

def draw_brushes(win, brush_maximum_radius, spiral_revolutions, spiral_angle_vector_acceleration, spiral_radius_acceleration, center_x, center_y, x_tremble_amplitude,
                 x_tremble_period, y_tremble_amplitude, y_tremble_period, light_intesity_period, light_intensity_period_displacement, maximum_light_intensity,
                 lowest_light_intensity, circleRGBred_weight, circleRGBgreen_weight, circleRGBblue_weight, brush_resolution, x_coordinate, y_coordinate):
    for brush_current_radius1 in range(brush_resolution * brush_maximum_radius, 0, -1): #The radius of the circles constituting the spiral
        brush_current_radius = brush_current_radius1 / brush_resolution

        #Origo of spiral is in the middle of the screen.

        #The direction of vector from origo is angle in radians
        spiral_angle_vector = ((brush_maximum_radius - brush_current_radius) / brush_maximum_radius * spiral_revolutions)
        spiral_angle_vector = spiral_angle_vector ** spiral_angle_vector_acceleration

        #The magnitude of vector is radius.
        spiral_radius = (brush_maximum_radius - brush_current_radius) ** spiral_radius_acceleration
        spiral_radius = spiral_radius ** spiral_radius_acceleration

        #If the spirals was an orbit tremble would be another orbit around that orbit. Moon to earth
        x_tremble = (spiral_radius * x_tremble_amplitude) * cos(spiral_angle_vector * x_tremble_period)
        y_tremble = (spiral_radius * y_tremble_amplitude) * sin(spiral_angle_vector * y_tremble_period)

        #With use of the above variables in this function, draw_brushes, the brushstrokes position around origo, center of screen, is calculated
        if x_coordinate != int(spiral_radius * cos(spiral_angle_vector) + x_tremble + center_x) or y_coordinate != int(spiral_radius * sin(spiral_angle_vector) + y_tremble + center_y):
            x_coordinate = int(spiral_radius * cos(spiral_angle_vector) + x_tremble + center_x)
            y_coordinate = int(spiral_radius * sin(spiral_angle_vector) + y_tremble + center_y)

            #Point is used to mark the circular brushs center with its radius brush_current_radius. Width is set to zero for cosmetic reasons, looks very choppy
            c = Circle(Point(x_coordinate, y_coordinate), brush_current_radius)
            c.setWidth(0)

            #light intensity due to distance from origo
            light_intensity_at_angle = int(sin(brush_current_radius/brush_maximum_radius * pi / 2 * light_intesity_period + light_intensity_period_displacement) * maximum_light_intensity + lowest_light_intensity)

            #color due to angle
            amplitude = amplitude_displacement = 0.5 #So that trigonometric function is 0<y<1
            circleRGBred = int(circleRGBred_weight * light_intensity_at_angle * (sin(spiral_angle_vector) * amplitude + amplitude_displacement))
            circleRGBgreen = int(circleRGBgreen_weight * light_intensity_at_angle * (sin(spiral_angle_vector + pi/2) * amplitude + amplitude_displacement))
            circleRGBblue = int(circleRGBblue_weight * light_intensity_at_angle * (sin(spiral_angle_vector + pi) * amplitude + amplitude_displacement))
            c.setFill(color_rgb(circleRGBred, circleRGBgreen, circleRGBblue))
            c.draw(win)


#The window settings where the spiral will be painted
width = 1350 
height = 730
background_red = 0
background_green = 0
background_blue = 0
win = GraphWin("My, painting circles", width, height)
win.setBackground(color_rgb(background_red, background_green, background_blue))

#Origo that is the reference point that is middle of coordination in window space
center_x = int(width / 2)
center_y = int(height / 2)

#Full screen spiral settings
zoom = 1.04 #by eye adjustment for visual preference
brush_maximum_radius = int(zoom * sqrt(center_x**2 + center_y**2))#Pythagoras

#Tremble is parable to painters hands tremble. Its factors to variables that are coordinates that gives the spirals path
x_tremble_amplitude = 0.1
x_tremble_period = 3
y_tremble_amplitude = 0.1
y_tremble_period = 3

#Acceleration is an exponent variable in the function draw_brushes
spiral_angle_vector_acceleration = 1.2
spiral_radius_acceleration = 0.8

#miscellaneous variables
spiral_revolutions = 2 * pi
brush_resolution = int(7) #lower integer for more "choppy" spiral

#So that variables is assigned a value before being called
x_coordinate_initial = y_coordinate_initial = 0

#light intensity due to distance from origo
light_intesity_period = 1.3
light_intensity_period_displacement = 0.15
maximum_light_intensity = 223
lowest_light_intensity = 22

#color due to angle. Weight must be 0<integer<1
circleRGBred_weight = int(1)
circleRGBgreen_weight = int(1)
circleRGBblue_weight = int(1)

#A single brushstroke at the time, repeated with for in range() to paint a spiral
draw_brushes(win, brush_maximum_radius, spiral_revolutions, spiral_angle_vector_acceleration, spiral_radius_acceleration, center_x, center_y, x_tremble_amplitude,
             x_tremble_period, y_tremble_amplitude, y_tremble_period, light_intesity_period, light_intensity_period_displacement, maximum_light_intensity,
             lowest_light_intensity, circleRGBred_weight, circleRGBgreen_weight, circleRGBblue_weight, brush_resolution, x_coordinate_initial, y_coordinate_initial)
```

Heres a spiral the program paints at its current settings

[image: spiral current settings]

Comment: Its not the if command that renders the picture quicker. it happens with or without the if command while minimizing the window that pops up while running the program. Maximizing the window and then the picture is painted in one go. Should i edit the question with the program with the docstring comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code formatting**:

- Black:

I recommend to use [**black**](https://github.com/psf/black) to format your code.

- Comments:

Just a personal preference: if the code in one line is getting too long, put the comment regarding the line on top of it, not in the same line to stay below a certain line length. I recommend 120, you can specify this in black.

**Cleaner code**:

- Do not use * imports:

When I go over your code, i am not able to see where the class `Circle` comes from. Is it from `math` or from `graphics`? Please only use explicit imports to only import what you need and make it easier to comprehend for other readers to find what code is used.

- Clarify 3rd party imports:

In the docstring you meantion a `graphics.py` module, but as a reader I dont know where this is and I can not import it. I can not run the code without it. Tell me where I can get it or provide it.

- Redefining variables from outer scope:

In `draw_brushes`, every argument variable overwrites a variable from the outer scope (module level) which can lead to nasty behaviour if you make a mistake.

- Dont call `int` on integers:

`int(1)` is just not needed.

- Configuration variables:

You use many variables to configure your drawing, maybe you can put all those in a configuration file or at least all in one place in the code.
Its a good practice to have module level variables, global variables, in ALL CAPS.

**Going deeper:**

You want more? Read [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Use [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/).
Run this code:`import this`